# Can't find @EnableSwagger annotation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, swagger

I just wanted to documente my spring rest application. Following the how to with springfox I added as a dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the jar is downloaded correctly but I can't find @EnableSwagger2 annotation nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here. springfox.documentation.swagger2 jar doesn't exist in springfox-core:2.7.0 They exist in the previous release of 2.6.1 when I was working with it before. I'm falling back to 2.6.1.

It's probably not a bad idea to check their 2.7.0 release notes to see if there's any bug fix that you need though: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/releases/tag/2.7.0

UPDATE: @EnableSwagger is actually in springfox-swagger2-2.7.0.jar not springfox-core.jar.

Answer (score 1):

It shoud be in `springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations` package.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
`@EnableSwagger2WebFlux` and `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc`

with the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

i use swagger 2.8.0， @EnableSwagger2 cannot resolve,  Then, I del the local maven repository ,then reImport it ,It is ok!